# How to plot a function that has a integer constant, for different values of the constant?

Tags: function, matlab, plot, matlab-figure

In MATLAB how do you plot a graph that has a integer constant, say the value is k and you want to get f(x) = (x.k).(exp(k+1) for k between the 1 to 3.

Here is the full question I am stuck on:
[image]

This is the result however there should be a simpler way of doing this, correct?
[image]

```
f = @(x,k)2ˆ(k+1)*x.ˆk.*exp(-2*x)/factorial(k);
xs = 0:1e-2:10;
plot(xs,f(xs,1),'r',xs,f(xs,2),'k',xs,f(xs,3),'b')
xlabel('x'); ylabel('f(x)');
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please post code as text, not images. so we can run it without having to type it. Also, please clarify what you don't like about your approach. Do you want the function `f` to output a matrix with the three curves instead of a vector each time? Or are you happy with the function as it is now and you only need a loop over `k = [1 2 3]`?

Comment: yeah, you  just plot 3, in the same plot. Check `hold on`

Comment: Sorry the code was a picture to begin with. I didn't know how to edit the comment to add code, so I decided to edit the original post. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Editing the question with additional information is the right way to do it. Comments can be deleted easily, the post itself should contain all relevant information.

Comment: Hello! Could you clarify your question? For matlab this is a fairly efficient and standard way do produce such a plot. There are indeed other ways do it but I wouldn't know which one to answer you with since I don't really understand what you mean by "simpler way". This is more or less as little code as you can to produce this figure. It is written in a way that makes is quiet easy to understand. It would help if you were a bit more specific